# how can we set a white color to the linerenderer

Tags: unity-game-engine, swipe

I am new to unity I have set the width and color for the line that should appear when I swipe the screen..but its not working, don't know whether my code is wrong

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LinesHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color c1 = Color.yellow;
    public Color c2 = Color.red;

    private GameObject lineGO;
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private int i = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        lineGO = new GameObject("Line");
        lineGO.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer = lineGO.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Mobile/Particles/Additive"));
        //lineRenderer.SetColors(c1, c2);
        lineRenderer.SetWidth(0.05F, 0);
        lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(i+1);
                Vector3 mPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 15);
                lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mPosition));
                i++;

                /* Add Collider */

                BoxCollider bc = lineGO.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                bc.transform.position = lineRenderer.transform.position;
                bc.size = new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
            }

            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                /* Remove Line */

                lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(0);
                i = 0;

                /* Remove Line Colliders */

                BoxCollider[] lineColliders = lineGO.GetComponents<BoxCollider>();

                foreach(BoxCollider b in lineColliders)
                {
                    Destroy(b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now  I am getting a pink color line while swiping on the screen.how can I change that color to white.
also is it possible to reduce the width of line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you're setting it right, but the pink color is the default material when the material is missing. I guess its just that it cannot find the material you're trying to apply.

You should check [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/587380/linerenderer-drawing-in-pink.html) out.

You'll find an example for the width and colors as well.